# .htaccess Use variables to check if subpage exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, url, mod-rewrite

I have a website, which is a one-pager JS-based site. It has different "subsites" and "categories", but since everything is controlled via JS, and since there are about 30 subsites and 50 categories, I have never created a "normal" subsite system, just like

```
www.example.com/subsite/category
```

Instead I have only the main site

```
www.example.com
```

and that's all, everything else is controlled via JS.

But I want to achieve better results on Google ranking, and for that I need to create subpages as well.
I want to keep the JS-based behavior, and that part is ready to handle the different URLs (`www.example.com/subsite/category`) the right way: it is checking the URL, takes the subsite and the category, and passes to the right JS as parameters. So my one-pager site acts like a multi-pager. And it's fine in this way.

At this point my `.htaccess` redirects all non-existing directories to the home page, keeping the URL itself unchanged, so the JS can use it properly.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

But I want to handle the non-existing subsites and categories as well, I want to 404 them. And I need to handle it via `.htaccess`.

So I thought maybe there is a way to handle the existing subsites and categories as variables in `.htaccess`, where all of their combinations are accepted, but all other goes to 404.

For example (in JS, since I don't know how to handle this in `.htaccess`):

```
var subsitesArray = ["foosite", "barsite"];
var categoriesArray = ["foocategory", "barcategory"];
```

So the valid URLs would be:

```
www.example.com/foosite/foocategory
www.example.com/foosite/barcategory
www.example.com/barsite/foocategory
www.example.com/barsite/barcategory
```

And all other would be non-valid, so 404.

If I would have to set all URLs manually, that would be 30*50 URLs... That's way too much.

Is it possible to solve it somehow in `.htaccess`?

**UPDATE#3**
Please update the code to support the following points:

- The `/site1` ... `/site30`, `/category1` ... `/category50` subsites are available on the server (index.html in these directories), so the .htaccess rules **should not** forward them to index.html (but let the "physical" files to be opened).
- So only `/site1/category1` ... `/site1/category50` ... `/site30/category1` ... `/site30/category50` variants should be redirected to index.html.
- `www.example.com/////site1///category2` (so a lot of `/` characters in-between) are still accepted, however should not be.
- When the link ends with a `/` character, it's not accepted, however it should be. `www.example.com/site1/category` is accepted, but `www.example.com/site1/category/` (ending with `/`) is not, however it should be.

Can you please update the code? These would be the final modifications, and it would work perfectly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This would seem to be a continuation of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427248/htaccess-open-main-page-if-file-or-folder-doesnt-exist-but-keep-url-url-rou) (except that previously you had "site" and "category" separated by a hyphen in the URL and "site" and "category" could also seemingly contain a hyphen (at least in your example), which would have made checking these independently in `.htaccess` pretty much impossible.)

> ```
> www.example.com/<site>/<category>
> ```

Following this URL pattern you could validate the `<site>` and `<category>` separately, so you would end up with 30 + 50 (80) directives, as opposed to 30 * 50  (1500) directives if you were to do this one-by-one.

For example, you could do something like the following in `.htaccess` (this replaces your existing rule):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not of the form "/site" or "/site/category" then stop here
RewriteRule !^[^/.]+(/[^/.]+)?$ - [L]

# Validate "site" (first path segment)
RewriteCond $1 !=site1
RewriteCond $1 !=site2
RewriteCond $1 !=site3
# etc.
RewriteCond $1 !=site30
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+) - [R=404]

# Validate "category" (second path segment)
RewriteCond $1 !=category1
RewriteCond $1 !=category2
RewriteCond $1 !=category3
# etc.
RewriteCond $1 !=category50
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+/([^/.]+)$ - [R=404]

# Front-controller
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

**UPDATE:** I removed the filesystem check entirely in favour of a rule that checks the format of the URL-path at the top of the file (ie. `RewriteRule !^[^/.]+(/[^/.]+)?$ - [L]`). If the requested URL-path does *not* (as denoted by the `!` prefix) match a URL of the form `/<value>` or `/<value>/<value>` then the remaining directives are skipped entirely and the request is not rewritten to `index.html`.

`!=site1` - The `!` prefix negates the expression, so it is successful when the expression does *not* match. The `=` prefix-operator makes this a lexicographical string comparison (exact match), rather than a regex. Each of the *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) are implicitly AND'd. So the rule is triggered only when all conditions do not match.

Where `$1` in each rule contains the value of the captured group from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In the first rule this contains the value of the first path-segment (the "site") and in the second rule this contains the value of the second path-segment (the "category").

If the "site" does not match in the first rule then a 404 is immediately triggered. If the "category" does not match in the second rule (only processed if the "site" is valid) then a 404 is immediately triggered.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/.]+) - [R=404]
> ```

This rule captures the first path segment in the URL-path and stores this in the `$1` backreference. So, given a URL of the form `/site/category` (or just `/site`) then this captures `site`. This is then used in the preceding `RewriteCond` directives to validate that `$1` contains one of the expected values. If all the preceding *conditions* are successful (ie. the first path segment does not match one of the permitted "sites") then a 404 is triggered. Note that I've restricted the path segment so it can no longer contain dots (this is the same pattern as used in the first rule).

> ```
> RewriteRule ^[^/.]+/([^/.]+)$ - [R=404]
> ```

This is similar to above, except that it captures the second path segment (ie. the "category") in the `$1` backreference. The preceding *conditions* then validate this. This is only processed if the preceding rule is not successful (ie. the first path segment matches a valid "site").

Define the custom error document as your `index.html` front-controller (in which you re-check the requested URL in JavaScript) then you can customise the response using JavaScript, as with all your other URLs (this should go at the top of the file):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

---

**UPDATE / ERROR CORRECTION:**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
> ```

There should be no `OR` flag on the 2nd *condition*! I've corrected this in the code above.

The `OR` on the 2nd condition would have prevented the rest of the code from doing anything! So any site/category URL would have resulted in a 404.

Comment: Dear @MrWhite, thank you - again. Yes, I thought it's a better idea to have "only" 30+50 (80) URLs than 30*50 (1500), that's why I decided to use the /<site>/<category> URL structure.
I would have a wish: Can you please modify the code to support cases where only the /<site> or the /<category> is present? Both are valid as well. So www.example.com/<site> and www.example.com/<category> are also valid.
Should I edit the original question with this modification request? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @lpasztor "to have "only" 30+50 (80) URLs than 30*50 (1500)" - That's 80 "directives" (or checks), you would still have 1500 possible URLs. Allowing both `/<site>` _and_ `/<category>` as well does complicate it somewhat (in order to avoid repetition). Do you have access to the main server config (or `<VirtualHost>` container)? Or are you limited to `.htaccess`?

Comment: Only `.htaccess`, plus all the possibilities of cPanel. And you are right, I expressed myself wrong, it's really still 1500 URLs. And I'm not sure if Google would like it at all. So maybe I should consider using either only `/<site>` or `/<category>`. And since people search mostly for categories (rather than sites), maybe that's better. So maybe in this case I should use the `# Validate "site" (first path segment)` part of code, but instead `site` use `category`. I think I update the question with this part as well. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. :-/ I created a .htaccess file where only your code is present (copy-paste), but instead of opening the index.html and letting the URL untouched, it gives me error saying `The requested URL /site1/category1 was not found on this server`. Can you please maybe check your code again? Thank you.

Comment: @lpasztor Sorry, there was a typo/error... there should be no `OR` flag on the 2nd _condition_ near the top of the file! I've updated my answer. (Have you set `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html`? That should still have allowed your code to handle the request, except that the HTTP status would have been a 404.)

Comment: Unfortunately still not OK. Now it accepts all weird URLs like `www.example.com/123` or `www.example.com/////wrong-site`. Interestingly it won't accept `www.example.com/123/456`, says 404. So when there are 2 path segments in the URL, it accepts only the the right ones like `www.example.com/site1/category2`. So the code has issues only with the case when only the first path segment is given. In that case it should accept only first path segment "sites" like `www.example.com/site1`, right? Thank you.

Comment: @lpasztor I've updated the code in my answer. It should now only process URLs of the form `/site` or `/site/category`. If the URL does not match that format then it is not passed to `index.html`. Previously it would have only validated URLs of the form `/site/category`, but URLs of a different format would have erroneously dropped through to `index.html`. I've also limited `site` and `category` so they cannot contain dots (to avoid conflicts with actual files, without needing a filesystem check).

Comment: Sorry to bother you with it, but still not OK. Now it blocks all the resources, won't load any of my files (.css, .js, .jpg - nothing). And when I try to open the site with the index.html `www.example.com/index.html`, it says 404. Could you please check it? Thank you.

Comment: @lpasztor No worries and sorry I made another typo/error! I wrote the correct _comment_, but missed the `!` prefix on the expression! It should be negated. ie. `RewriteRule ^[^/.]+(/[^/.]+)?$ - [L]` should be `RewriteRule !^[^/.]+(/[^/.]+)?$ - [L]` - I've updated my answer and added more (possibly overlapping) explanation. However, I realise this still doesn't address your UPDATE#1 and #2 - I'll have a look at that later.

Comment: Now it looks much-much better, thank you. Please don't care about UPDATE#1 and #2 for now. So now the right site- or category names are opening only, that's good. But I can still see, that for example `www.example.com/////site1` is still accepted. `site1` is valid, but the `/////` should not be accepted. And regarding UPDATE#2: I would like to be able to open `www.example.com/category1` as well. (So from the second path segment.) But I can't add it simply to the first path segment, because in that case `www.example.com/category1/category1` would be also accepted. Which is not good.

Comment: To continue my previous comment: Also please note, I just realized, that when the good URL ends with `/`, it's not accepted, however that's a valid URL. So for example `www.example.com/site1` is accepted, but `www.example.com/site1/` is not, however it should, since it's a valid URL for the same page. Thank you.

Comment: Should I put all the open points together into an update to the original question? There would be still some fine tuning missing, also a finalized idea with some minor modifications regarding the original request, and I don't want to disturb you with my comments. Thank you.

Comment: Please check UPDATE #3. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to have one rule: `RewriteRule ^/?(site1|site2|site3)/(category1|category2|category3)/?$ index.html [L]`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Wow, nice and clean, thank you! However it still has one of the earlier issues: for some reason it accepts when multiple `/` characters are given. For example `www.example.com////site1/////////category1` is also accepted (redirects to index.html), however it should be 404. Can you please provide a fix for that? Thank you.

Comment: Merging into one rule is OK if you have just 3 sites and 3 categories, but in this case you have 30 sites and 50 categories - I would keep them as separate conditions (or perhaps merge into small groups - but readability may suffer. It's usually easier to scan/maintain a vertical list). The multiple slashes are an entirely separate issue. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69473909/369434) to the following question to resolve this. [Removing Double Slashes From URL By .htaccess does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69469146/369434)

Comment: To add to what MrWhite just said, the multiple slashes are a quirk of Apache because it condenses multiple slashes to one before the rewrite rules are run.  You can use a separate rule that has a condition that examines `%{THE_REQUEST}` which has the raw URL before Apache mucks with it. The rule to remove the multiple slashes should come *before* your other rules.  (And despite MrWhite's "readability" concerns, I still prefer a single rule, even if it has fifty elements.)

Comment: @MrWhite and @Stephen Ostermiller. As hopefully the last request in this topic: Can you please show me how would that 1 liner `RewriteRule ^/?(site1|site2|site3)/(category1|category2|category3)/?$ index.html [L]` look with separate conditions/groups? Just to see, which would be better for this 30+50-project. Thank you.

Comment: That is what MrWhite put in his answer.  The separate conditions are like `RewriteCond $1 !=site1`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you. Actually I choose your solution (as a comment, I can't makr it as accepted answer), because as I wrote in the UPDATE#3, the solution from MrWhite needed one more change, and without that it's not working as should. But MrWhite thank you also for all of your help and patience to me.